# How to get Potential Owner from task summary - JBPM 6.5

Tags: task, jbpm, business-process-management, kie-workbench

I am developing a task inbox and from my frontend I am calling `http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/query/task?potentialOwner=potOwner` for getting task summary, but this query does not retrieve the Potential Owner.

I know we can add business data to subject/description using `#{}` into task properties from business process modeler, but how can I set there the potential owner?

Comment: generally, in kie server the task should have a group. do you have a group in that task?

Comment: Yes! But when you calle query/task the Group is not an output in task-summary.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the query service, the potenial owner is in the table: PEOPLEASSIGNMENTS_POTOWNERS

http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2016/01/advanced-queries-in-jbpm-64.html